# Publishing to local Nuget gallery time out after 100s, but actually works anyway

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

We are trying to use Nuget for our internally generated packages.  We have setup a local nuget server and verified that we can see it from Visual studio.  If I copy a .nupkg file into ~/Packages manually they show up and can be added to a new project in Visual Studio using the nuget package manager.

However, when we try and push to our local nuget server we get timeouts.  We are unable to find any logs or anything to point us in the direction of the error.  The .nupkg file actually shows up in ~/Packages, and can still be added to a project using nuget package manager in Visual Studio.

Would like to stop the timeout so my build script doesn't fail the build when we publish a new package to our local nuget server.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Turns out this is not a nuget issue, or our scripts.  It was the server we were running it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not a nuget issue, or our scripts.  It was the server we were running it on.